# How to know a pdf is text based or image based in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, pdf, ocr

How do identify a pdf is image based or text based in node.js?

in my code below (*using express app*)

```
app.post("/upload", upload.single("file"), async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.file);

  try {
    let dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
    let data = await pdfParse(dataBuffer);

    // Save the extracted text to a new .txt file
    await fs.promises.writeFile(
      `./uploads/${req.file.originalname}.txt`,
      data.text
    );
    console.log("Text extracted and saved successfully.");
    res.send(
      `File uploaded and text extracted successfully. The text file is saved as ${req.file.originalname}.txt.`
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res
      .status(500)
      .send(
        "An error occurred while extracting text from the PDF or saving the extracted text to a file."
      );
  }
});
```

I'm converting each pdf files received in the back end to text files. The purpose of doing this is to implement a search feature by looking inside the content of the pdf and index the pdf file that contains the keyword in the front end.

```
app.get("/search", async (req, res) => {
  const keyword = req.query.keyword.toLowerCase(); // Convert keyword to lowercase
  const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, "uploads");
  let filesContainingKeyword = [];

  try {
    const files = await fs.promises.readdir(directoryPath);

    for (let file of files) {
      if (file.endsWith(".txt")) {
        let filePath = path.join(directoryPath, file);
        let data = await fs.promises.readFile(filePath, "utf8");
        let lowerCaseData = data.toLowerCase();
        if (lowerCaseData.includes(keyword)) {
          // Convert data to lowercase
          let index = lowerCaseData.indexOf(keyword);
          let preview = data.substring(index, index + 100) + "..."; // Get a substring of 100 characters around the keyword
          let pdfFile = file.replace(".txt", "");
          filesContainingKeyword.push({ filename: pdfFile, preview: preview });
          console.log(`Found keyword in ${filePath}`);
        } else {
          console.log(`Keyword not found in ${filePath}`);
        }
      }
    }

    res.send(filesContainingKeyword);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Unable to scan directory: " + err);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
  }
});
```

The catch is sometimes the pdf will be image based and thus returns no text to perform search operation. I found tesseract to perform OCR and create the text files, but it is resource intensive and doesn't requires to text based pdf files. What I'm trying to do is before performing the conversion, I need to check the received pdf file is text based or image based, also there may be chances of pdf file contains both text and images. So it would be helpful suggesting a solution for this problem.